# mysql query to find sum of different names

Tags: mysql

I use similar queries (10) as following queries (modified) to find sum

```
SELECT sum(amount) AS amount 
  FROM `students` 
 WHERE sex='M' 
    && name in ('salil', 'anil', 'gaikwad')
```

...and:

```
SELECT sum(amount) AS amount 
  FROM `students` 
 WHERE sex='M' 
    && name in ('salil1', 'anil1', 'gaikwad1')
```

i want to make a single query of the above 10 queries. is it possible?

Comment: What do you do with the 10 queries - are their sums to be combined, compared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNION

```
SELECT 'subset1', sum(amount) AS amount FROM students WHERE sex='M' and name in ('salil', 'anil', 'gaikwad')
UNION
SELECT 'subset2', sum(amount) AS amount FROM students WHERE sex='M' and name in ('salil1', 'anil1', 'gaikwad1')
```

However, you probably query these sets of students for a reason, perhaps anil, salil and gaikwad are one group of students. If so, you should reflect this in the database structure, not in your code.

You could add a field 'SUbset' or 'Group' or whatever that is, to students table, so it looks like this:

```
name group_id
salil 1
anil 1
gaikwad 1
salil1 2
...
```

Then you can do

```
select group_id, sum(amount) from students group by group_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
SELECT sum(amount) AS amount 
FROM    students  INNER JOIN
        (SELECT 'salil%' Val UNION SELECT 'anil%' UNION SELECT 'gaikwad%') s ON students.NAME LIKE s.Val
WHERE   sex='M'
```

This allows you to use the values in the second *Table* to join with *LIKE*.

Comment: I suspect 'salil1' is not really a student name, just an unfortunate example of the OP.